# automata, check string is accepted by language | C++

Tags: c++, finite-automata, automata

This is my automata, and it Regular Expression for this language is `(aaa*b|ba)a*`

[image]

I want to make a C++ program for check input string is accepted by this language or not.

This program get the string and print `Accepted` or `Rejected`

For example:

*input:* aaaba - *output:* Accepted

*input:* baa - *output:* Accepted

*input:* aaa - *output:* Rejected

Comment: **Rejected** ...........

Comment: No idea which idiot upvoted this _"question"_.

Comment: You probably misunderstood my comment (sorry it was just sarcasm and a pun). Your question is actually _too broad_ and off-topic, hence _rejected_.

Comment: I've developed a nice framework for finite state automata in c++, may be it's useful for you: [STTCL](https://makulik.github.io/sttcl/).

Comment: Feel free for any queries.

Comment: The code and your dfa are exactly same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

bool check_string(const std::string& s) {
  static constexpr int INV = -1;
  static constexpr int INITIAL_STATE = 0;
  static constexpr int ACCEPTING_STATE = 3;
  static const int transition_table[5][2] = {
    //  a    b
    {   1,   2   },  // 0
    {   4,  INV  },  // 1
    {   3,  INV  },  // 2
    {   3,  INV  },  // 3
    {   4,   3   }   // 4
  };

  int state = INITIAL_STATE;
  for (char c : s) {
    if (c != 'a' && c != 'b') return false;
    state = transition_table[state][c - 'a'];
    if (state == INV) return false;
  }
  return state == ACCEPTING_STATE;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  if (argc != 2) {
    std::cerr << "Usage: check str\n";
    return 1;
  }
  if (check_string(argv[1]))
    std::cout << "Accepted\n";
  else
    std::cout << "Rejected\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have most of the job, as your DFA is absolutely correct. Allow me to do the remaining job.

Let us consider a function that will take the string as an argument and return true or false depending on whether the string is accepted or rejected.

**Key Idea**

The main idea is to use the finite state machine states and process the string step by step. The code is very simple and straight forward to write, because its just the finite state machine traversing through different states and **processing the input string through different states just like your automata does.**

**We begin with state 0 and follow the diagram of your automata**

Here is a brief description.

if the string begins with a, the next state is 1 . If the string begins with b the next state is 2 and if string begins with neither,the string is rejected.

the very next character is a regardless of the fact that current state is 1 or 2 and the next character is not a , the string is rejected.

if the next character is a , the next state is 3 or 4 depending on what the current state is.

Once we take care of this, if current state is 3, then we only have to consider aa......aaa till end of string and if some other character occurs at any point the string is rejected.

If current state is 4 , we again take care of the aa......aaa but we also have to see now that there is also one occurrence of b after aa.....aaa and then again we take care of aa........aaa.

```
bool check_string(string str)
{
 int state = 0;    

 if(str[i] == 'a')
  { state = 1; ++i; }

 else if(str[i] == 'b')
  { state = 2; ++i; }

 else return false;

 if(str[i] != 'a')
  return false;

 else if(state == 1)
  {state = 4; ++i; }

 else if(state == 2)  
  {state = 3; ++i; }

 if(state == 3)
 {
   while(i < str.length())
   {
    if(str[i++] != 'a')
     return false;
   }
   return true;
 }

 if(state == 4)
 {
  while(i < str.length()&& str[i++] == 'a')
   {

   }
  if(i == str.length())
   return false;
  else if(str[i] == 'b')
  {
   while(i < str.length())
   {
    if(str[i++] != 'a')
     return false;
   }
   return true;
  }
  else return false;
}
```

Comment: Meh. `if` `else` cascades or `switch` gets messy for handling states and transitions.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  Not in this case, because we have minimal nesting and most if else is without nesting. It only gets messy when you do the nesting

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Just follow the digram and the code will read to you like a piece of code.

Comment: I prefer other techniques (State Design Pattern).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ If you have better answer, please post it. I would love to see a better answer.

Comment: I've done some efforts on the state design pattern (see the link). It's too broad to bring that up in an answer for such an unspecific question.